# How to do an image in math mode

Tags: math-mode, graphics

For a logic assignment I need to do something that looks like the one in red:

[image: wanted]

I do know that I've not done a *minimal work* but I truly don't know how to do something like this. All I can think about is this code:

```
\begin{align*}
&\underbrace{\Gamma}_{\quad} \\
&\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\varphi \\ 
& -- \\
& \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace p_0
\end{align*}
```

And it doesn't look good at all.

Comment: for the last part you can use $\frac{\varphi}{p_0}$. For the upper part I don't know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(**UPDATED** to include the picture as part of a formula)

Tikz is probably overkill for this, but easy to do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(P.north)]
    \node (G) {$\Gamma$};
    \node[below=1.5ex of G] (P) {$\frac{\varphi}{p_0}$};
    \draw (G.east) -- (P.north) -- (G.west);
  \end{tikzpicture} 
  \in \text{DER}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Done as a stack.

REVISED SOLUTION (with pointed vee and one less package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\stackMath
\def\mystrut#1{\rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}}
\def\thinvee{\raisebox{-2pt}{\mystrut{45}\kern.8\dimexpr-.7071pt\mystrut{-45}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\stackunder[0pt]{\stackon[-4pt]{\thinvee}{\Gamma}}{\frac{\varphi}{~p_0~}}\in \textrm{DER}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\stackMath
\def\myvee{\raisebox{2pt}{\scalebox{3}[1.3]{$\bigvee$}}}
\def\thinvee{\stackengine{.5pt}{\myvee}{\color{white}\myvee}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\[
\stackunder{\stackon[-5pt]{\thinvee}{\Gamma}}{\frac{\varphi}{~p_0~}}\in \textrm{DER}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i don't know whether the point on the vee is significant, but the rounding doesn't look quite like something a mathematician would produce.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Point taken, though it came from a scale of `\bigvee`.

Comment: the scaling alone doesn't cause such a distinct curve.  i don't know `stackengine` well enough to understand what's happening, but from experiments with scaling only, it seems that the exaggeration results from the way the `white` is applied.  with scaling only, the inner angle remains sharp.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Fixed.

Comment: much nicer after edit.